# How to select various elements of a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping a website using scrapy where I want to extract a few details such as price, product description, features etc of a product. I want to know how to select each of these elements using css selectors or xpath selectors and store them in xml or json format.

I have written the following code skeleton. Please guide me what should I do from here.

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy
import time


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myquotes'
    
    start_urls = [
            'https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/ref=gbps_ftr_m-9_2862_dlt_LD?node=15529609011&gb_f_deals1=dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL%252CEXPIRED%252CSOLDOUT%252CUPCOMING,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,MARKETING_ID:ship_export,enforcedCategories:15684181,dealTypes:LIGHTNING_DEAL&pf_rd_p=9b8adb89-8774-4860-8b6e-e7cefc1c2862&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-9&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=15529609011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=AA0VVPMWMQM1MF4XQZKR&ie=UTF8'
                        
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        
        
        all_div_quotes = response.css('a-section a-spacing-none tallCellView gridColumn2 singleCell')                    
        
        for quotes in all_div_quotes:
            
            
            title1 = all_div_quotes.css('.dealPriceText::text').extract()
            title2 = all_div_quotes.css('.a-declarative::text').extract()
            title3 = all_div_quotes.css('#shipSoldInfo::text').extract()        
        
            
        yield{
                'price' : title1,
                'details1' : title2,
                'details2' : title3                                  
                
            }
```

I am running the code using the command:

```
scrapy crawl myquotes -o myfile.json
```

to save it inside a json file. The problem with this code is that it is not returning the title, product price, product description as intended. If someone could help me with how to **scrape** the product name, price and description of an amazon page it would be of great help.

Comment: Are you debug your code?

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to check and verify CSS selectors is using `scrapy shell`. 
In your case, I have listed the selectors you can use along with the code:

Name: `response.css("#productTitle::text").get()`

Price: Price was not available in my country so couldn't test it.

Description: `response.css("#productDescription p::text").getall()`

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The normal method to solve an error like this starting at the top. I think your very first css selector is too detailed. On using the selector gadget, the general css selector is

```
.dealDetailContainer
```

Yield the whole response without a for loop and check the output to understand that you're getting some kind of a response.

For products individually, when I scraped a different amazon link the css selector for the product name is

```
#productTitle::text  -># is not a commented line of code here
```

Basically, you're going wrong with the css selectors. Use the CSS Selector Gadget and before using the command to output it into json, do a normal crawl first.

Answer (score 0):

generallly what you could do is

```
Name: response.css("#productTitle::text").extract()

Description: response.css("#productDescription p::text").extract()
```

With this you should be good to go.
CSS selector are more constant so they are usually a better bet than using xpath and consequently the way to go